# Calling http post after calling http get

Tags: typescript, angular-httpclient

I am working with an Angular 4 application and I am trying to retrieve a shipment id to store in my transaction before writing the transaction to db.  Each call is working by themselves, but how can I make sure that the shipment Id value comes through before making the post call?  Below is the code I have:

```
//From component
saveTrans(): void {

  //Retrieving Shipment Id
  if (this.newTransaction.VehicleId != '') {
    this._data.getShipmentId(this.newTransaction.VehicleId).subscribe(s => this.newTransaction.ShipmentId = s);
  }

    this.item.Transactions.push(this.newTransaction);

    this._data.saveTransaction(this.item).subscribe(() => this.getInventoryTransactions());

    this.closeTrans();
}


//From data service
public getShipmentId(vehicleNbr: string): Observable<number> {
  return this._http.get(url)
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
    .map(response => response.json());
}

public saveTransaction(item: Inventory): Observable<string> {
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.jsonHeader });

  return this._http.post(url, JSON.stringify(item), options)
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
    .map(response => response.toString())
}
```

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly, you want to call `saveTransaction` only after `ShipmentId` is set on `this.newTransaction` (therefore, after the `Observable` returned `this._data.getShipmentId` emits the response)?

What I don't get though is why you would want to save a transaction which doesn't have a `ShipmentId`.

Comment: I have three different transaction types Consume, Receive, Transfer.  I would only have a vehicle # entered for Receive transactions; otherwise, the shipment id would be 0.  The above is slightly simplified from what I actually have.  I am doing some validation, and the call to retrieve the shipment id is only occurring for Receive transactions.